# Musescore 3: How prevent notes of muted instrument from displaying on the piano keyboard

Tags: musescore

Is it possible to prevent showing notes on the playback keyboard that are not are playing on the score?

**`Image Playing Solo`**
[image: MuseScore screenshot, no muted instrument]

Even with Mute Instrument, the muted part's notes still appear on the Piano Keyboard.

**`Image Playing Mute`**
[image: MuseScore screenshot, piano muted]

I think that only *`two`* notes need to appear on Piano Keyboard not *`four`*.
**Is it possible prevent that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muting the instrument only turns the volume down to zero; it doesn't stop that instrument from being played. That is, it's still played when muted, just silently.

To prevent an instrument's notes from showing up on the keyboard, you must turn off the `Play` setting for each of that instrument's notes.

1. Select all notes for that instrument.
2. In the Inspector's `Select` section, click `Notes`.
3. Uncheck `Play`.